# Entity Framework executesqlcommand in same transaction as savechanges

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

The problem I have is that I need to update 15000 rows by deleting them and reinsert them. This has to happen in a single transaction.
When I remove the rows row by row this is very slow. Inserting goes fine.

Is there a possibility to execute an ExecuteSqlCommand statement in the same transaction as the savechanges of the context with the insert statements?

Comment: prior to EF6 you have `TransactionScope`, since EF6 you use `DbContext.Database.BeginTransaction` or `DbContext.Database.UseTransaction`, see this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843

Comment: I tried it but unfortunately it is not supported on Sql Azure. :(

Answer (score 0):

you should use Entity Framework 6 Power Tools Community Edition fro reverse entity and its relation generations and use your Entity framework as it was in EDMX